# Can't connect bluetooth devices without restarting after laptop has been on for some time

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I've had the annoying issue of not being able to pair with bluetooth devices on my laptop unless I restart it. This happens for multiple headsets which all pair without issue on other devices and on this laptop as well after the restart.

Some of the pairing behavior includes:

- I click the device to pair. The macOS ui shows the device as paired and the device says "bluetooth connected". The headset doesn't show as an audio output device and after a few seconds the bluetooth disconnects
- With another headset, I click to pair the device and it either loads for a while before failing or connects and immediately disconnects.

I've tried

- all the reset options under the bluetooth menu shown by pressing option + shift
- stopping the audio daemon with `sudo killall coreaudiod`
- clearing the nvram
- `sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext` + `sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext`

I'm not sure what to do to troubleshoot this issue. I've tried looking at the logs in `console` when trying to connect a headset and it fails, but I'm not sure what exactly to look for there.

I'm using a 2019 Macbook Pro on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2.

Comment: Same issue on MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020) running macOS Big Sur 11.5.2.

Comment: @Volsk if you have android file transfer installed try quitting that process when this happens. Worked for me :)

Comment: Actually this happened again with Android File Transfer not running

Answer (score 0):

This happened again and seems to have been fixed by stopping the "Android file transfer" process using Activity Monitor as suggested here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8631469

edit: the issues connecting happened again but stopping Android File Transfer didn't fix it. Leaving this answer up in case it works for anyone